# Хранение пользователей в бинарном дереве. Алгоритм и БД

Tags: php, mysql, алгоритм, binary, nested-sets

Здравствуйте! Для сетевой компании нужно спроектировать хранение пользователей в бинарном дереве. Пишу на php и mysql. А конкретней на yii2.

Думаю использовать Nested Set, но пользователей будет более 10 000. И каждый раз, вставляя пользователя нужно переобновлять дерево. Ведь под каждым человеком будут другие люди, и на основе них будут начисляться выплаты.
[image: Nested Set]

К примеру:
Всего в бинарном дереве 1500 человек, и когда появится 1 человек внизу, он может дать вознаграждение каждому партнеру выше, вплоть до корневого места.

Разумно ли использовать Nested Set, обычно его используют для древовидных комментариев или категорий, может быть есть что лучше? Возможно есть другой путь, который я пока не тыкнут лицом, не увижу? Очень очень нужна помощь.
[image: Расположение людей в бинарном дереве]

Comment: *нужно спроектировать хранение пользователей в бинарном дереве* Когда будет сделано 80% работы, выяснится, что иногда дерево может быть и не очень бинарным... *обычно его используют для древовидных комментариев или категорий* Не знаю, кто это Вам сказал, но это сто пудов была шутка. *Разумно ли использовать Nested Set* Имхо да. И заодно подумать о просто дереве.

Comment: А зачем всё это? MySQL btree индексы умеет, и hash выбирайте любой на вкус. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html

Comment: ПС: 10000 записей - это не много.